# How to configure static index.html in Wildfly which has ReactJs code

Tags: reactjs, wildfly, static-content

I have build my ReactJS Application with npm build and final I have bundle.js and other dependencies  which is bundled using with Babel and webpack modules.

In my final dist folder which has index.html which is pointing bundle.js ( as below )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the dist folder which generated after npm build.

Locally I am able to launch my application using npm start, but now my question is how can I deploy this static folder into Wildfly 18.x ? so I can launch my ReactJS code.

Answer (score 2):

WildFly is an application server meant for hosting JVM-based web applications, so it's unusual to deploy JS-based app on it.

What you need to do is to create a war file form your dist folder and then deploy it in WildFly using its management console or JBoss CLI.

You can find some more details on war files [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/war-file) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)). There are also details on creating wars for ReactJS apps [here](https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/build-war-npm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784590/how-to-convert-nodejs-application-to-war-file). Finally WildFly 18 documentation on application deployment is available [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/18/Admin_Guide.html#application-deployment).